# ListView doesn't appear list button?

Tags: android, listview

I want to custom each line of List view is Button with the text view inside it  .

But it's not work!

It's only show a button that i have created in the first layout .

What can i do for fix ? Many thanks

Here's my code :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
    ListView lv ;
    ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;

    ArrayList<String> al ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstView);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        al = new ArrayList();
        al.add("cho");
        al.add("phuong");
        al.add("hello");
        al.add("bye");
        al.add("love");
        listViewAdapter= new ListViewAdapter(this , R.layout.button , al);
        lv.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
```

This is adapter :

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context  The current context.
     * @param resource The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use when
     */
    Activity context;
    int layResID;
    ArrayList<String> object;
    public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, int resource , ArrayList<String> object) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.context=context;
        this.layResID = resource;
        this.object = object;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

            convertView = inflater.inflate(layResID, null);
        }
        Button btn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.view);
        String string = object.get(position);
        btn.setText(string);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

This is main xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.macbook.note.MainActivity"
    android:background="#1A237E"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstView"
        android:divider="#1A237E"
        android:dividerHeight="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>
    </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is custom layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_list"
        android:textSize="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your ArrayAdapter's super call to the following

```
super(context, object);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you do not have specified the current count of your items which should be created inside of list view. You have two options:
1. Call other constructor of ArrayAdapter so ArrayAdapter class will handle it for you:

```
public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, int resource , ArrayList<String> object) {
    super(context, resource, object);
}
```

2. Override ArrayAdapater.getCount() inside your adapter class:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.object.size();
}
```